# Excel Timeline- want to remove the 'Day' from 'time level' filter in the excel timeline

Tags: excel, vba

Want to hide/remove the 'Day' option from Excel Timeline.
Did try using vba but not sure how to hide/remove it.

`ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Timeline_Date").Slicers("Date").TimelineViewState. _ Level = xlTimelineLevelDays`